# creating a select element and setting value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to create a form with Javascript to get around a CORS issue (meaning: I cannot submit this form using AJAX because the API I am using does not allow it).

However I am having problems setting the value with Javascript. The following does not work for me:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");

var formElement = document.createElement("select");
formElement.value = "foo";
formElement.id = "bar";

form.appendChild(formElement);

document.body.appendChild(form);
```

see [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/capaziriba/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select` elements have `option` elements to go with it:

```
var formElement = document.createElement("select");
var optionElement = document.createElement("option");

optionElement.value = "foo";
optionElement.text = "foo"
optionElement.selected = true;

formElement.appendChild(optionElement);
formElement.id = "bar";
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/tebasecahi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks, going to marked this as the answer (because it was first).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create the select list (before you create options):

```
var selectList = document.createElement('select');
```

Then add that to the form:

```
form.appendChild(selectList);
```

Then you can create the option and append that to the `selectList`:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = 'foo';
option.id = 'bar';
option.selected = true;
option.text = 'foobar';
```

Finally, append that to the `selectList` and then the form to the `body`

```
selectList.appendChild(option);
document.body.appendChild(form);
```

See [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/capobeqema/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score -2):

Try using `setAttribute` method instead of value.

```js
var form = document.createElement("form");

var formElement = document.createElement("select");
formElement.setAttribute('value', "foo");
formElement.id = "bar";

form.appendChild(formElement);

document.body.appendChild(form);
```

Comment: Please consider posting a reason for the minus 1. The code I have posted is valid and working.

Comment: `select` elements need options, else it's just a blank select. And your code didnt change anything from OP's, you use `setAttribute` instead of just defining the property.

Comment: That's false. If you inspect with the original code, you do not see a value property on the select element. By using `setAttribute` you are able to add this prop which is what the question was: "However I am having problems setting the value"

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question from setting select value to setting option values.

Comment: All I knew is I needed to set a value that the server could grab. If I knew it was options I wouldn't have asked on stack overflow.